# How to safely future-proof my exit from a dual-job scenario

Tags: software-industry, united-states, software-development, remote-work

I'm a Java developer with 9 years experience, living in the U.S. I've been working two, full-time, remote software engineering jobs for over two years now and I'm getting bored at one of the jobs. I want to stay with company A and leave company B, but I'm unsure of how this will affect my resume and future career choices. I don't think this will really matter until I go look for a new job, once I finally leave company A, but I want to start preparing for this now.

I assume an employer doesn't want to see that I worked two jobs at once on my resume, but I've built up good references and experiences, so I feel torn. Should I just pretend that my time with company B never happened? Are there any other tips on "resolving" the two-job scenario so that I can proceed with a single job going forward?

Comment: How do you feel about getting caught lying on your resume and then trying to talk your way out of it? Some people thrive on this kind of dodging about, while others consider it terrifying and dishonest.

Comment: If my resume only mentions job A, and I have solid references at company A, I think I'm safe there. Trying to mention both seems terrifying.

Comment: Do both A and B know about each other? Was double dipping in violation of any of their policies ?

Comment: @Hilmar No they don't know about each other. Possibly violates policies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only times I have seen multiple companies with obvious overlapping time periods is under few situations:

- One full time and one part time.
- Multiple part time jobs. I know that many adjunct professors have to work at multiple college/universities at the same time.
- One most of the year (teaching) and the other during holidays. The holiday job could be at a movie theater, amusement park, national park, summer camp...
- One as an employee and the other as a contractor.

These can be easily explained especially if the contractor position is 100% unrelated to the full time employment.

If I noticed that the resume listed what seemed to be two full time jobs, I know that would be a question I would be asking during the interview. I would have concerns about burnout, and if you can focus on the job I am hiring for; but those could be addressed by your explanation. The thing that would concern me the most was potential time-card fraud. How do I know that you won't be doing this in the future? How do I know that you won't be using the hardware I am providing to do work for another company?

Even if you don't mention one of the jobs on the resume, because the resume doesn't have to list all employment, you will have to list all jobs if they want to do a background investigation. Depending on the position they could also do a financial background check which could expose the 2nd paycheck.

Don't manipulate the dates of employment on the resume to try and hide the two year overlap. If they call the companies then the employment dates on the resume won't match what the company ave. This could lead to questions and concerns.

Regarding the resume, I think all options leave you with issues that could invite more questions:

- List both, and they will ask about the double dipping.
- List one, and the other will come out of they do a background check.
- List one, and you could leave a multi-year gap in the resume depending on the order of events.
- Manipulate the dates, invites too many questions if they try and confirm employment history.

The question for you is where in the hiring process do you want this to be noticed/discovered?

Comment: "List one, and you could leave a multi-year gap in the resume depending on the order of events." - I don't understand this part. Could you please elaborate? Overall great points, thanks.

Comment: @Karen34 Presumably you started one job before the other, which means that if you select the job you started second, there will be a gap.